# Teradata : Sum up values in a column

Tags: sql, teradata

**Problem Statement**

Example is shown in below image :

The last 2 rows have the patterns like "1.283  2  3" in a single cell. The numbers are seperated by space in the column. We need to add those nos and represent in the format given in Output.

So, the cell having "1.283 2 3" must be converted to 6.283

**Challenges facing :**

1. The column values are in string format.
2. Add nos after casting them into integer
3. Donot want to take data in UNIX box and manipulate the same.

[image]

Comment: What's your Teradata release? What's the maximum number of values? Of course this is a totally bad data model violating 1st Normal Form. It should be fixed instead.

Comment: Release 13.10 ... actually the data which i am getting in col2 is by some calculation .. i just need to sum up these nos.

Comment: "some calculation" can you show which calculation? Why don't you do the sum during that calculation?

Comment: @dnoeth - some calculation include manipulation of data in Mainframe side which we are not aware of. The MF developers wont change their code , as they need the data in this format only. So the same file gets dumped in Db. We need to parse that data in db side itself. 
We can easily perform in UNIX side, but we are not allowed to fetch this in Production environment.
I hope you are undertanding the problem.

Comment: Ok, what is the size of this VARCHAR and the maximum number of values?

Comment: Var size is kept 1000

Answer (score 2):

In TD14 there would be a built-in table UDF named STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE, before you need to implement your own UDF or use a recursive query.

I modified an existing string splitting script to use blanks as delimiter:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE Strings
(
  groupcol INT NOT NULL,
  string VARCHAR(991) NOT NULL
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO Strings VALUES (1,'71.792');
INSERT INTO Strings VALUES (2,'71.792 1  2');
INSERT INTO Strings VALUES (3,'1.283     2  3');

WITH RECURSIVE cte
 (groupcol,
  --string,
  len,
  remaining,
  word,
  pos
 ) AS (
  SELECT
    GroupCol,
    --String,
    POSITION(' ' IN String || ' ') - 1 AS len,
    TRIM(LEADING FROM SUBSTRING(String || ' ' FROM len + 2)) AS remaining,
    TRIM(SUBSTRING(String FROM 1 FOR len)) AS word,
    1
  FROM strings
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    GroupCol,
    --String,
    POSITION(' ' IN remaining)- 1 AS len_new,
    TRIM(LEADING FROM SUBSTRING(remaining FROM len_new + 2)),
    TRIM(SUBSTRING(remaining FROM 1 FOR len_new)),
    pos + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE remaining <> ''
 )
SELECT
  groupcol,
  -- remove the NULLIF to get 0 for blank strings
  SUM(CAST(NULLIF(word, '') AS DECIMAL(18,3)))
FROM cte
GROUP BY 1
```

This might use a lot of spool, hopefully you're not running that on a large table.